# How to configure TFS 2018 shell extension to use the right workspace?

Tags: windows, tfs, explorer, shell-extensions

I'm using the Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2018 Explorer shell extension
(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-vcw.TfsShellExtention)

Everything worked well.

Now i got another workspace checked-out but the shell extension still works only for the files in the previous workspace.

How do i reconfigure the shell extension to work (=show icons) for the files of the other workspace?

Comment: Even now deleted the previous workspace mapping, but still, TFS shell extension shows icons for the old workspace folder only.

Comment: try to reastart the windows.

Comment: @Shayki: Well, yes, that helped. But i was hoping for a softer solution. It is a TFS build machine.

Comment: I don't know another solution :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered this problem several times, which helped me is restart the machine.

I know that is not the best solution, but the extension probably is not the best extension...